# An expression of non-boolean type specified; in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view in SQL Server, which contains a WHERE clause, which is the following:

```
WHERE andon_digitaloutput.on_when_other_lights_off
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

> an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

**VIEW:**

```
FROM andon_device AS ad
  JOIN (SELECT
      id AS id,
      do_name AS do_name,
      color AS color,
      do_destination AS do_destination
    FROM andon_digitaloutput
    WHERE andon_digitaloutput.on_when_other_lights_off = 1 ) AS c
  LEFT JOIN andon_device_product adp
    ON ad.id=adp.device_id_id
  LEFT JOIN andon_product ap
    ON adp.product_id_id = ap.id
WHERE ad.id NOT IN (SELECT
    andon_event_active.device_id
  FROM andon_event_active);
```

Comment: It needs to be compared to something...  I'm assuming it's a bit, so `= 1` for true.

Comment: I tried "WHERE andon_digitaloutput.on_when_other_lights_off=1) AS c)" , but I got the following error:  "Incorrect sintax near '')" in that line.

Comment: You have far too many brackets, which are not balanced according to the error. Remove all but the bracket before `select` and the bracket after `WHERE andon_digitaloutput.on_when_other_lights_off = 1` i.e. you will be left with 2 brackets.

Comment: Put the whole script which is giving you that error. Does this query fail? `SELECT id, do_name, color, do_destination FROM andon_digitaloutput WHERE on_when_other_lights_off = 1;` It's the view's subquery removing all that's redundant (which is quite a lot honestly). You should check the type of `on_when_other_lights_off`. Your quoted script as-is is missing lines and/or parenthesis.

Comment: You `where` clause also has too many brackets, remove all but the 1 before the `select` and the one after `andon_event_active`. That said, I don't believe your query as posted will still be giving you the same error.

Comment: @Andrew, I tried the query you gave me and it ran perfectly, I put the complete script at the top. The error still remains. Remove the brackets. I tested the query you gave me and it worked perfectly, I put the full script on top. The error still remains. Remove the brackets. Now I get an error near the where clause: Incorrect syntax

Comment: `NOT ad.id IN` should be `ad.id NOT IN`

Comment: And you need a join condition for `c`.

Comment: @SaulSalcedo, still there?

Answer (score 0):

This is the `where` clause:

```
WHERE andon_digitaloutput.on_when_other_lights_off
```

As the error message explains, SQL Server does not support boolean types.  SO you need some comparison.  Perhaps one of the following:

```
WHERE andon_digitaloutput.on_when_other_lights_off = 1
WHERE andon_digitaloutput.on_when_other_lights_off = 'T'
WHERE andon_digitaloutput.on_when_other_lights_off <> 0
```

It all depends on what the column contains and what logic you want.

Also, you should learn to use table aliases.  This will simplify your code, making it easier to write and read.  The code might then look like:

```
WHERE ado.on_when_other_lights_off = 1
```